# NoClassDefFoundError in Hadoop wordcount

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to java, I tried to setup and run hadoop in windows 10. however, when I run the wordcount main function, I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

This is the file wordcount.java

```
package org.apache.hadoop.examples;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> [<in>...] <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < otherArgs.length - 1; ++i) {
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[i]));
        }
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,
                new Path(otherArgs[otherArgs.length - 1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(itr.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }
            result.set(sum);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }
}
```

However, as I am new to java, I do not know what this error is and how to fix this. 
Note: I have installed Java, Cygwin and added Cygwin and hadoop/bin to the system environments.

P.S. I found the solution for this problem. I just needed to mark an option in itelliJ to use provided libraries in the runtime as well.

Comment: How are you calling your Java code?  You would need to specify that its classpath will contain the jar file(s) for Hadoop, which would be set in the CLASSPATH env var, and is probably not hadoop/bin ...

Comment: @moilejter. Thank you for your comment. I simply click the run button to run this project. I have also allowed maven to import all dependencies, which I believe does the job. However, I added the folder containing the jar file to dependencies from  module settings in intelliJ. However, it did not work